# Error in untar( ) while using R

Tags: r, tar

I am new to the R programming language and am having basic issues with it. I want to untar a file, but it has not been able to work for me.

Here is the code that I enter:

> untar("CD_data.tar", exdir="data")

It then returns the following error message:

```
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/gnutar: No such file or directory

Warning message:

In untar("CD_data.tar", exdir = "data") :
  ‘/usr/bin/gnutar -xf 'CD_data.tar' -C 'data'’ returned error code 127
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: What does `Sys.getenv("TAR")` give you? `/usr/bin/gnutar`? Where is your gnutar program installed? It cannot be found in `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: Which operating system do you run?

Answer (score 9):

R on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) seems to set a wrong `TAR` environment variable.

You can fix this by adding the following to your `.Rprofile` (or executing it manually):

```
Sys.setenv(TAR = '/usr/bin/tar')
```

Alternatively, you can provide the `tar` path as an argument when calling `untar`.

Answer (score -1):

My 2 cents is that you are using a mac and have not installed tar. You are getting value 127 because the command is not found within your $PATH and it's not a built-in command (which is usually the case if you were in unix...

In other words you need to install tar.

Or run it in linux.

Comment: That’s not the reason – `tar` obviously exists on the system. R erroneously believes that it’s supposed to use /usr/bin/gnutar` but that’s wrong on OS X 10.9.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well. I obviously don't use a MAC. That's just a best guess from my perspective.